# Average, Total and Transpose

Tags: sql-server, average, transpose

I have this query below:

```
SELECT distinct COUNT(Status) AS [Transactions], sender AS [Supplier],
left(DATENAME(mm, Date_Reported), 3) AS Month, DATENAME(yyyy, Date_Reported) AS Year
 FROM TX
 and Date_Reported >= DATEADD(MONTH, -13, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
GROUP BY DATENAME(mm, Date_Reported), DATENAME(yyyy, Date_Reported), sender
ORDER BY sender, Year, Month DESC;
```

It gives me a table like below:

```
TX | Supplier | Month | Year
```

Now the above can have X rows with the same supplier and a value associated with it like below:

```
**TX | Supplier | Month | Year**
1  | A        | Oct   | 2017
5  | A        | Jan   | 2017
3  | A        | Mar   | 2018
2  | A        | Sep   | 2017
```

This is the case for all of the suppliers, so instead of a long winded table with many rows I want distinct suppliers and their values in a concise table as below:

```
Supplier | May 17 | Jun 17 | Jul 17 ... | May 18 |
```

I would also like to add two extra columns: the average of the last 13 months (ie May 17 - May 18) and also the total of the last 13 months, so the final table should look like this:

```
Supplier | May 17 | Jun 17 | Jul 17 ... | May 18 | Average | Total
```

I appreciate I am asking a lot, but I hope someone can help me with ONE SINGLE query that can do ALL of the above.

I thank you in advance :)

Comment: I'll suggest the same thing i always do with stuff like this, do it in your presentation layer. Trying to do something like this in your RDBMS with SQL is going to require dynamic SQL, and is far harder to achieve.

Comment: I would love to but i need to automate this query into ssrs visual studio and it will be difficult to do that then

Comment: There are plenty of examples on SO of creating PIVOT queries using dynamic SQL

Comment: If it's SSRS, use a matrix instead of a tablix. Far far easier.

Comment: @Larnu how would i do this with the first table i have above?

Comment: What are you expecting your output to look like here? Also, do you have a calendar table?

Comment: Supplier | May 17 | Jun 17 | Jul 17 ... | May 18 | Average | Total

Comment: Like this with distinct supplier names

Comment: Post actual sample data and expected result, don't say "something like..." Give us something to work with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172660/discussion-between-taz-and-larnu).

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do something like this:

```
SELECT sender AS [Supplier],
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(Date_Reported) = 5 AND YEAR(Date_Reported) = 2017  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [May 17],
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(Date_Reported) = 6 AND YEAR(Date_Reported) = 2017  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Jun 17]
GROUP BY sender
ORDER BY sender
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing the without it being manual in entering the month and year?

Comment: Yes.  Depends on what you want.  You could wire up something easily which returns a fixed number of months prior to date.  If you wanted something that returned a dynamic number of months, though,  then you would have to use dynamic SQL (e.g. a T-SQL procedure using a loop that generates a string containing SQL similar to my example that you would then call with `sp_executesql`.